# Running ARM assembly code in Android

Tags: android, shell, adb

I've been following the guide posted [here](http://peterdn.com/post/e28098Hello-World!e28099-in-ARM-assembly.aspx), trying to get this Hello, World program to run on my Samsung Galaxy S3. It's rooted already, and I successfully pushed the "hello" file onto the sdcard. Now when I enter the shell as the superuser (# instead of $), and try to run the file, I get "cannot execute - permission denied". I used chmod 755 hello to see if that would fix it, still nothing.

Is there something I'm missing? This is my first time fiddling around with Android, just got the phone, and wanted to see if I could get this to work. Very new to it all.

Thanks!

Comment: What does `file hello` say?

Comment: Strangely, it says "file not found". But it's definitely there - I see it when I use ls -l

Comment: Try running it on your host machine on the same file. Does it say it's a ARM ELF file?

Comment: It says: "hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped". Sorry about the long time it took to respond, I do appreciate your help!

Comment: I do "./hello" in the directory with the file and it says cannot execute. I was doing "hello" before, was wondering why it was saying it couldn't be found. Still, can't execute :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your SD card is mounted with `noexec` option. Copy the file to another partition like `/data` and try running it from there